# Polymorphism Assignment Statement

Tags: java, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I have question regarding polymorphism about its assignment statement, for Example this is The Super class

```
   public class Person {

            private String firstName;
            private String middleInitial;
            private String lastName;
            private int age;

            public Person(String firstName,String middleInitial , String lastName , int age){
                setFirstName(firstName);
                setMiddleInitial(middleInitial);
                setLastName(lastName);
                setAge(age);
            }

            public void setFirstName(String firstName){
                this.firstName = firstName;
            }

            public String getFirstName(){
                return firstName;
            }

            public void setMiddleInitial(String middleInitial){
                this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
            }

            public String getMiddleInitial(){
                return middleInitial;
            }

            public void setLastName(String lastName){
                this.lastName = lastName;
            }

            public String getLastName(){
                return lastName;
            }

            public void setAge(int age){
                this.age = age;
            }

            public int getAge(){
                return age;
            }

            public String toString(){
                return String.format("First Name: "+getFirstName()+"\nMiddle Initial: "+getMiddleInitial()+
                                        "\nLast Name: "+getLastName()+"\nAge: "+getAge());
            }
    }
```

And this is The Derived Class

```
 public class Employee extends Person{

        private Contact contact;

        public Employee(String firstName,String middleInitial , String lastName , int age, Contact contact){
            super(firstName,middleInitial,lastName,age);
            this.contact = contact;
        }
public String toString(){
        return String.format(super.toString()+contact.toString());
    }
}
```

Now my question is what's the Difference Between these assignment statements ?? and what are the difference ? I know Employee is a Person but I want to know what's the difference between these two:

```
 Person employee1 = new Employee();
    Employee employee2 = new Employee();
```

and This

```
 Employee employeeKyle = new Employee();
    Person employeeKyel2 = employeeKyle;
```

I am kinda having a hard time about these .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first one you have 2 OBJECTS, both are of the type Employee, and you have 2 different references to them, one being a Person reference and the other being an Employee reference.

In the second case, you have 1 OBJECT with 2 REFERENCES pointing to it, being one a Person and another an Employee.

The object is always of the type you've instantiated it with the *new* keyword (in this case, the object is always an employee). You can, however, have different types of references pointing to the actual object (the references can be either of the type of the object or of one of its superclasses).

Comment: in the first assignment, Person employee1 = new Employee(); does this mean that I can't access the methods in employee? only the Person class?

Comment: Yes, unless you cast it. ((Employee) employee1).setFirstName("Bob") would work.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, yes.
So, basically a Person reference will only "see" stuff from the Person class, even if the object it's pointing to is a Employee object.

Comment: THanks leo! you got the question right, now I fully understand it, I was just wondering why would other people use that as an assignment. one last thing though, if I would do this Person p1 = new Employee() , does this mean I can't really do this? p1.getEarnings() earnings is part of Employee class?

Comment: ;)
No, you can't. When you do  Person p1 = new Employee(), p1 only sees a person, so it can't see what's specific to Employee.
If you want to access any Employee specific stuff, you must cast it to Employee, like Gillaume said:
Employee emp = (Employee) p1;

Answer (score 1):

The first one creates an `Employee` that is referenced as a `Person`, and an `Employee` referenced as an `Employee`. `employee1` has only `Person` methods, while `employee2` has both `Person` and `Employee` methods.

The second one creates an `Employee` and then creates a `Person` reference to the same `Employee`. Only methods defined in the `Person` class will be available to the `employeeKyel2` instance, while `employeeKyle` will have all the `Employee` methods.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you only have one object, with two pointers to it. If you modify `employeeKyle`, then `employeeKyle2` will be modified as well (they are the same object). The fact that you refers to `employeeKyle2` as a Person and not an `Employee` is only helpful for the methods you're allowed to use on that reference. Under the hood, it's still pointing to the same `Employee` object, so if you later cast `employeeKyle2` as an `Employee`, it will work and not throw a cast exception.

In the first example, you create two different objects, that's the only difference. They are two `Employee` objects under the hood, but you can only use `Person` methods on `employee2`.